# How do I fix splotched color?

Tags: color

Basically as you can see the photo has this weird purple saturation on the right side. I know it has something to do with overlay or color blending modes but I can't quite connect the dots on how to match the right to the left.

[image]

The second question I have is, when I do paint over grayscale image like this, how do I avoid having a uniform single color? Like I can eyedrop the left side of him, and paint the right side with just that color, but it would be better to have different shades of that blue-ish gray to look realistic. Should I use the gradient tool to paint a selection overlay? If so, how do I make my own color gradient instead of these presets?:

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify your second question a bit more?

Comment: Do you need this? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/138412/69916

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a few **adjustment layers** and masking.

Create a selection for the affected area. You might want to do this with pen tool for precise selection. The left side won't matter much because we'll mask it soften and blend with left portion of image. Right side edges of the jacket/clothes are the boundaries, so selection needs to be better.

I used quick selection tool for demonstration, you can use pen tool for more control. You can use same selection for all the adjustments and modify the masks individually. That's what I'll do. Also I've highlighted (yellow arrows) which portions will need soft brush in mask area adjustments:

[image]

1. Apply `Selective Color` and reduce the values of Magenta, Red a bit:

   [image]
2. Use `Hue and Saturation` layer to reduce saturation of Magenta, Red
   and blue a bit:

   [image]
3. Now, you might have lost some blue color details. So add a `Color Balance` layer to 'bring' back some blue and green maybe.

   [image]

   Another layer to make it a bit warm:
   [image]
4. Now the right side look a bit brighter (ignore if that's 'natural'
   or you want it as it is), so add a `Levels` layer and make it a bit
   less bright and add a soft mask so it affects only right portion.
   And make other tweaks/fixes by cross checking previous layers:

   [image]

**Layers Panel:**

[image]

**Note:** All those adjustment layers, especially color related are **not necessary**. Feel free to ignore which you don't feel like needed.

The idea is to tweak things and mask and try to see what works best. You'll need to mask with soft brush at some points. Reduce or emphasize the adjustment layers using mask wherever necessary. Try different sizes of brushes and different opacity values. Try adjusting opacities of layers themselves.

---

About the color changing part, you can use **Gradient Map**. Your question is a bit unclear to me, but if you want to change colors of the clothes, you need to decide 3 or 4 main colors (some darker, some brighter) of the look you want to create and use them in `Gradient Map` adjustment layer (use a selection where you want to apply). Something like this:

[image]

Or if you want to change entire image look and feel to a single color, you can use a solid color (or paint in a new layer manually with a solid brush, only the areas which you need) and try changing its Blend Mode to different modes like Multiply/Screen. See what works best for you. A few examples:

[image]

There's a `Photo Filter` adjustment layer too in case you want to try.

You may also want to check [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/138412/69916) answer.

Comment: that's incredible work and looks perfect. I'll use this technique when I need more accurate color correction. 

The 2nd question, basically what I'm trying figure out how to have color complexity for a more natural 'lifelike' look. Where if I just paint over with a single color, it does come across as a bit artificial. Especially important for various skin tones I think

Comment: @AlexB. I've edited my answer for better explanation and some changes in second half. If it's still not what you want, we will need to discuss it more. Maybe showing some example like what kind of look you need?

Comment: I've used your techniques. Hopefully this turned out alright. Let me know if there's things I should fix here. 


 https://imgur.com/hwxFOFF

Comment: @AlexB. looks fine, still you can improve it. If you see the photo as whole, the highlighted area, you may want to add some blue tone to it using a new Color Balance layer. https://imgur.com/lahnOvx

Comment: It looks a bit grey and off.

Comment: Also the 2nd question I found an answer in a Youtube video. Basically what I meant was how to create a color palette, which then would be turned into a gradient map. Then using masks this would be used to create skin blemishes, different shades etc in parts of the photo to avoid a uniform color, and instead a more natural look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127837/discussion-between-vikas-and-alex-b).

Comment: okay I tried to fix it further. Hopefully it's not overly saturated now:

https://imgur.com/2vdYjnE

It might be around the neck area, I'll just history brush it back for some more natural tone

Comment: @AlexB. you can click the link above, we can discuss it in chat if you want. Comments are not allowed for extended discussion. Yes, the image looks better now!

Answer (score 5):

You can quickly fix the purple discolouration using a brush set to Hue.
Use the dropper to grab colour from the left side, then just use broad strokes over the tinted side. You need to be more careful than I was near the face to save the poor guy going grey. This was literally 30 seconds' work.

[image]

If you want slightly more variance in the colour, grab different parts of the coat & shirt. Some parts of it will come out very blue, others very grey. Pick a couple of areas with trial & error & see how it comes out. You can use 100% Opacity, but use low Flow, so you can paint it in slowly.

The right side then probably needs a bit of a Sharpen to crisp it up a bit, & a little Burn to darken where it's faded. Again, another 30s quick dash…

[image]

I often find with tasks like this, you can either carefully mask your working area, or carfully 'colour inside the lines'. Either will work & each will take about the same time to do.

Comment: wow that's a really awesome technique, I had no clue about the brush set to hue feature! Thank-you. I can see now how that discoloration came about, because of how much blurrier that part of the image is compared to the left. I'll play around with the sharpen tool you suggested, maybe even some patching or clone stamping!